Casorati matrix and homogeneous linear difference equations
Here is a cleaned-up version of the question:
I found the following in a linear algebra textbook:

If a Casorati matrix is not invertible, the associated signals being tested may or may not be linearly dependent. However, it can be shown that if the signals are all solutions of the same homogeneous difference equation (described below), then either the Casorati matrix is invertible for all $k$ and the signals are linearly independent, or else the Casorati matrix is not invertible for all $k$ and the signals are linearly dependent.

The proof for this statement is not given in the book, and I have searched quite a bit but cannot find it mentioned anywhere else. Can you please point out where I may be able to find a proof for this result?
